# Why can methods in Go only be declared on types defined in the same package?

Tags: methods, go

The [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/3) says the following:

> You can only declare a method with a receiver whose type is defined in the same package as the method. You cannot declare a method with a receiver whose type is defined in another package (which includes the built-in types such as int).

Is there a reason for this other than avoiding everyone building their own methods off `int` and `string`? I've Googled around, but can't find anything referencing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that if you could define methods on other packages' types, you could modify the behavior of other packages. This is because the method set of a given type can have an effect on how values of that type are used.

Consider, for example, the `fmt.Println` function. When you pass an argument to `fmt.Println`, it will print a string representation of that value based on a set of rules. One of those rules is that if the type of the value has a `String() string` method (that is, it implements the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface), then that method will be called in order to obtain the string representation of the value.

Thus, imagine that we have a package, `foo`, and that package has a type, `FooInt`, defined as follows:

```
type FooInt int
```

Now imagine that this package also has a function, `PrintFooInt`:

```
func PrintFooInt(f FooInt) { fmt.Println(f) }
```

This will print the integer value of `f`. But let's say that you (in a different package, say `main`) were able to add methods to `FooInt`. Then you could do this:

```
func (f FooInt) String() string { return "foobar!" }
```

This would actually change the behavior of `foo.PrintFooInt`, which shouldn't be possible from outside the package.